# CSS border-radius only rounds one corner of modal div window

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, sass

When I use the border-radius property on modal divs (divs that pop up over my normal content), the four corners do not all round themselves.  **One or two** corners will round, but not all four.

*Here is a link to the image, I can't yet post images on Stack Overflow* *(Note the top left corner in the image)* https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Randall-Coding/misc/master/border_round_err.png

I have tried using all the different cross-browser attributes for border rounding

```
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;   /* Also tried 20px 20px  */
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -o-border-radius: 20px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
```

Here is my CSS code using the mixin (note it looks the same with or without the mixin).

```
div.contact_window{
    background-color: white;
    /*border-radius: 20px 20px;  */  /*other way I have tried it */
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;   /* Also tried 20px 20px  */
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    width: 60%;
    min-width:700px;
    max-width:800px;
    height: 520px;
    overflow:scroll;
    left:20%;
    top: 130px;
    z-index:10;
    display: none;
    display: block; /*DEBUG */
}

div.mask{
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display:none;
  display:block; /*DEBUG */
}
```

And HTML code is as follows

```
    <div class="contact_window" id='#contact_window'>
        <%= render 'contact' %>
    </div> <!-- end div.contact_form -->

    <div class="mask">
```

I am rounding the corners of my other divs without any issue.

So I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this issue and/or has some idea what is going on here?

*I'm using Firefox, but this also holds true on my Chromium browser.  My operating system is Ubuntu Linux 18.04.

*Here are the links to the SCSS and HTML files.
HTML https://github.com/Randall-Coding/misc/raw/master/index.html

CSS (SCSS) https://github.com/Randall-Coding/misc/raw/master/main.scss

edit* When I inspect the element it still shows border-radius:20px

Comment: what do you see when you inspect it? is the border-radius getting overwritten by something else?

Comment: Inspection shows border-radius:20px (that is what I am using now).  It is not crossed out.  I posted the source files for CSS and HTML in my comment to Josh below.

Comment: My guess is something was over riding it, but if it is not crossed out it is a little confusing, can you manually force the corners to round with css when you are in the inspector?

Comment: Rockwell I think you misunderstand the situation, there already is one corner rounded (see the link to the image).  The corners should all round together, not just the top left corner

Comment: I don't know what I could change to round the other three.  The attribute is already added.  I posted the source files at the bottom of my answer now (edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I broke this down attribute by attribute and it turns out the issue is with the setting

`overflow:scroll`

Which forces the window to have sharp corners where the scrollbars would be located be.

So the answer is to remove `overflow:scroll` from the CSS

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to achieve the rounding without the mixin by simply passing the border radius directly?

Unless you intend on changing the radius of each corner individually, it's probably best that you just pass one value to border-radius that will be applied to each corner. This can be done by doing:

```
border-radius: 20px;
```

instead of:

```
border-radius: 20px 20px;
```

Try this as your mixin instead (clearer naming):

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
  -moz-border-radius: $radius;
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
  border-radius: $radius;
}
```

and pass one value

```
@include border-radius(20px);
```

Comment: That is how I originally tried it.  I should have included that in the question.  I tried it without the mixin and using a single value.  Just tried it again, still only one corner rounded.  *also just tried it with the mixin and a single value, same result

Comment: Then you must have some existing CSS class that is overwriting the style. Upload your entire code to https://jsfiddle.net/ and then I might be able to help.

Comment: I added the links to the bottom of the question.  The stylesheet will need to be linked or just plopped in between <script> tags.  Stylesheet is scss

Answer (score 0):

Try border-radius in % like

```
border-radius:100%;
```